# get grand total when display value in same page after click submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have form it display value in same page after click submit button,it's all work fine 
but i need to get grand total value when i click the submit button every time.
please can any one help me

here is my full code.

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" type="text/css">

<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Add Sales</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#stk").change(function(){

document.getElementById('total').value=document.getElementById('pric').value * document.getElementById('stk').value;
}); 

 });

 function add_values(){
 
         if(document.getElementById('edit_guid').value==""){
     if( document.getElementById('stk').value!="" &&  document.getElementById('total').value!="" ){
     
                    if(document.getElementById('stk').value!=0){
                   
    sell=document.getElementById('pric').value;
    disc=document.getElementById('stk').value;
    total=document.getElementById('total').value;
    item=document.getElementById('guid').value;
  
    roll=parseInt(document.getElementById('roll_no').value);
 
    $('<tr id='+item+'><td><lable id='+item+'roll >'+roll+'</label></td><td><input type=text  readonly="readonly" value='+sell+'></td><td><input type=text  readonly="readonly" value='+disc+' ></td><td><input type=text  readonly="readonly" value='+total+'> </td></tr>').fadeIn("slow").appendTo('#item_copy_final');
    document.getElementById('stk').value="";
    document.getElementById('pric').value="";
    
    document.getElementById('roll_no').value=roll+1;
    document.getElementById('total').value="";
   
    document.getElementById('guid').value="";
    
}
}else{
     alert('Please Select An Item');
    }
    }
 
    }
        </script>
        
<body>

    <form name="form1" method="post" id="form1" action="">
                                  
                  <input type="hidden" id="roll_no" value="1" >    
                 <div align="center">
                  <input type="hidden" id="guid">
                  <input type="hidden" id="edit_guid">
                        
                  <table class="form" >
                      
     <tr>
                          <td>price</td>
        <td></td> 
                          <td>stk</td>
                          <td>totall</td>
                      </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>

   <td><input type='text' class='form-control' id="pric" name="pric"></td>
   <td><input type='text' class='form-control' id="stk" name="stk"></td>
   <td><input type='text' class='form-control' id="total" name="total1"></td>
   <td><input type="button" onclick="add_values()"  id="add_new_code" value="submit" class="round"></div></form></td></tr>
                  </table>
                          
                       <div style="overflow:auto ;max-height:300px;  ">
                          <table class="form" id="item_copy_final" style="margin-left:45px ">
                    
                    </table>
                   </div>
                     </div>
         <div class="mytable_row ">
   <form>
   <div align="center">
   <table>
   <td>grand totall</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="grand_tot" name="grand_tot"></td>
   </table>
   </div>
   </form>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here i need to collect all the total value as the grand total

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ch510dk3/2/  ..

Answer (score 0):

I try But , Its Take The Current Text Value In GrandTotal and Overright it ....

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" type="text/css">

<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Add Sales</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#stk").change(function(){

document.getElementById('total').value=document.getElementById('pric').value * document.getElementById('stk').value;
}); 

 });

 function add_values(){
 
         if(document.getElementById('edit_guid').value==""){
     if( document.getElementById('stk').value!="" &&  document.getElementById('total').value!="" ){
     
                    if(document.getElementById('stk').value!=0){
    
         var current_TOTAL = document.getElementById('total').value=document.getElementById('pric').value * document.getElementById('stk').value;
   
    var sell=document.getElementById('pric').value;
    var disc=document.getElementById('stk').value;
    var total=document.getElementById('total').value;
    var item=document.getElementById('guid').value;
    var grand_total =document.getElementById('grand_tot').value;
    var full_total = 0;
    full_total = 0;
    var full_total = document.getElementById('total').value;
   
    roll=parseInt(document.getElementById('roll_no').value);
 
    $('<tr id='+item+'><td><lable id='+item+'roll >'+roll+'</label></td><td><input type=text  readonly="readonly" value='+sell+'></td><td><input type=text  readonly="readonly" value='+disc+' ></td><td><input type=text  readonly="readonly" value='+total+'> </td></tr>').fadeIn("slow").appendTo('#item_copy_final');
    document.getElementById('stk').value="";
    document.getElementById('pric').value="";
    
    document.getElementById('roll_no').value=roll+1;
    document.getElementById('total').value="";
   
    document.getElementById('guid').value="";
    
    document.getElementById('grand_tot').value=full_total;
    
}
}else{
     alert('Please Select An Item');
    }
    }
 
    }
        </script>
        
<body>

    <form name="form1" method="post" id="form1" action="">
                                  
                  <input type="hidden" id="roll_no" value="1" >    
                 <div align="center">
                  <input type="hidden" id="guid">
                  <input type="hidden" id="edit_guid">
                        
                  <table class="form" >
                      
     <tr>
                          <td>price</td>
        <td></td> 
                          <td>stk</td>
                          <td>totall</td>
                      </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>

   <td><input type='text' class='form-control' id="pric" name="pric"></td>
   <td><input type='text' class='form-control' id="stk" name="stk"></td>
   <td><input type='text' class='form-control' id="total" name="total1"></td>
   <td><input type="button" onclick="add_values()"  id="add_new_code" value="submit" class="round"></div></form></td></tr>
                  </table>
                          
                       <div style="overflow:auto ;max-height:300px;  ">
                          <table class="form" id="item_copy_final" style="margin-left:45px ">
                    
                    </table>
                   </div>
                     </div>
         <div class="mytable_row ">
   <form>
   <div align="center">
   <table>
   <td>grand totall</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="grand_tot" name="grand_tot"></td>
   </table>
   </div>
   </form>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you sir,but how can i get grand total value in here?

Comment: you have to store an last total value into one variable and then you have to sum of current total value + last total value .. in your sub total ..

Comment: jsfiddle.net/ch510dk3/2 .. like this

Comment: i try it but,it's not coming .

Comment: how to add this total value submission for on click submit button

Answer (score 0):

Finally  i got the answer this may help to some one.

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" type="text/css">

<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Add Sales</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

//$("#stk").change(function(){

//document.getElementById('total').value=document.getElementById('pric').value * document.getElementById('stk').value;
//}); 

$("#pric,#stk").keyup(function () {
    $('#total').val($('#pric').val() * $('#stk').val());
});

 });

 function add_values(){
 
         if(document.getElementById('edit_guid').value==""){
     if( document.getElementById('stk').value!="" &&  document.getElementById('total').value!="" ){
     
                    if(document.getElementById('stk').value!=0){
                   
    sell=document.getElementById('pric').value;
    disc=document.getElementById('stk').value;
    total=document.getElementById('total').value;
    item=document.getElementById('guid').value;
 //item=document.getElementById('guid').value;
    roll=parseInt(document.getElementById('roll_no').value);
 
 
    $('<tr id='+item+'><td><lable id='+item+'roll >'+roll+'</label></td><td><input type=text  readonly="readonly" value='+sell+'></td><td><input type=text  readonly="readonly" value='+disc+' ></td><td><input type=text  readonly="readonly" class="submited-total" value='+total+'> </td></tr>').fadeIn("slow").appendTo('#item_copy_final');
    document.getElementById('stk').value="";
    document.getElementById('pric').value="";
    
    document.getElementById('roll_no').value=roll+1;
    document.getElementById('total').value="";
   //document.getElementById('roll_no').value="";
    document.getElementById('guid').value="";
 
 submitedTotal = 0;
 $('.submited-total').each(function(){
  submitedTotal = this.value; 
 });
 if(document.getElementById('grand_tot').value==""){
        document.getElementById('grand_tot').value=submitedTotal;
    }else{
    submitedTotal =parseFloat(document.getElementById('grand_tot').value)+ parseFloat(submitedTotal);
    }
    $('#grand_tot').val(submitedTotal);
}
}else{
     alert('Please Select An Item');
    }
    }
 
    }
        </script>
        
<body>

    <form name="form1" method="post" id="form1" action="">
                                  
                  <input type="hidden" id="roll_no" value="1" >    
                 <div align="center">
                  <input type="hidden" id="guid">
                  <input type="hidden" id="edit_guid">
                        
                  <table class="form" >
                      
     <tr>
                          <td>price</td>
        <td></td> 
                          <td>stk</td>
                          <td>totall</td>
                      </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>

   <td><input type='text' class='form-control' id="pric" name="pric"></td>
   <td><input type='text' class='form-control' id="stk" name="stk"></td>
   <td><input type='text' class='form-control' id="total" name="total1"></td>
   <td><input type="button" onclick="add_values()"  id="add_new_code" value="submit" class="round"></div></form></td></tr>
                  </table>
                          
                       <div style="overflow:auto ;max-height:300px;  ">
                          <table class="form" id="item_copy_final" style="margin-left:45px ">
                    
                    </table>
                   </div>
                     </div>
         <div class="mytable_row ">
   <form>
   <div align="center">
   <table>
   <td>grand totall</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="grand_tot" name="grand_tot"></td>
   </table>
   </div>
   </form>
  
</body>
</html>
```